# Styling DIV Arrow Outlines - Making hollow triangles

Tags: css, html, transparency

thank you for all the years that I've never had to post a question and simply just searched!

Now, I'm trying to draw an arrow with a DIV. Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/18LzN.png

So far code such as that below will draw a triangle: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YOHq.png

```
.arrow-small {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 0; 
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 80px 600px 50px 600px; 
border-color: transparent transparent blue transparent;
}
```

One method I've tried has been to create a smaller filled triangle to place on top of the large one which would create the arrow outline that I'm looking for, however I can not find a way to make the top div show the page background to complete the effect.

For clarity, my questions:

1) How does one create a backgroundless arrow with a div?

2) Or, how does one show the body background in a div ontop of another div that is not transparent?

Answer (score 2):

[**jsFiddle Demo: Florescent Green Arrow**](http://jsfiddle.net/f6LAN/)

I don't think that will work because you're covering something opaque with something else opaque.  If you're able to use CSS3, the following might suit your needs:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .chevron {
        position: absolute;
        width: 50px;
        height: 10px;
        top: 20px;
        background-color:red;
      }
      .left
      {
        left: 0px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(340deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(340deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(340deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(340deg);
        transform: rotate(340deg);
      }
      .right
      {
        left: 43px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(20deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
        transform: rotate(20deg);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='chevron left'></div>
    <div class='chevron right'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I discovered transforms on [this page](http://www.red-team-design.com/how-to-create-slick-effects-with-css3-box-shadow), which was given in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635545/box-shadow-with-triangle-shaped-border-to-create-chevron-shaped-div), which sounds close to yours.