# css sandpaper not working ie7 and 8

Tags: javascript, css

I am currently using css sandpaper (http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/) to rotate a specified div. It works great in firefox, and ie9.

But in ie 7 and 8 i get the following error in my console:

```
CRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'split': object is null or undefined 
cssSandpaper.js, line 563 character 21
```

here is the CSS i have setup:

```
-sand-transform: rotate(340deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(340deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(340deg);
-o-transform: rotate(340deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(340deg);
```

Anybody have any ideas on what the problem could be?

Cheers Dan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096855/styling-div-arrow-outlines-making-hollow-triangles  Could this help?

Comment: that's not the problem i am having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran into the same problem. I have (quick)fixed the issue by changing cssSandpaper.js.

Added:

```
if(propertiesStr === undefined) {
    return false;
}
```

Between:

```
var propertiesStr = parsedRule[1];
var properties = propertiesStr.split(';');
```

Not the best solution but I don't have the time to debug the entire script ;-)